# Best Practice to call WCF service hosted in windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

```
EndpointAddress _endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + szWord_Operation_Ip + "/CalcService");
var channel = new ChannelFactory<Process_Word_Document.ICalcService>(_binding, _endpoint);
var _client = channel.CreateChannel();
_client.Update_Document_Properties(szFilePath);
```

OR

```
EndpointAddress _endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + szWord_Operation_Ip + "/CalcService");
using (Process_Word_Document.CalcServiceClient _client = new Process_Word_Document.CalcServiceClient(_binding, _endpoint))
  _client.Update_Document_Properties(szFilePath);
```

Service ....

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalcService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Boolean Process_Word_Document(string szFilePath);

}


public class CalcService : ICalcService
{
 public bool Process_Word_Document(string szFilePath)
 {
   //.....Code
 }
}
```

I just want to know the Difference between these calling method
 which one is better & which will give me better performance.

Comment: SOAP, I'd assume? Just use the contracts.

Comment: Can you post Update_Document_Properties method code also?What it does will give a little broader picture.

Comment: thanks for the replay. Please Check I have Added service Code